# Is it possible to point a GKE K8 ingress point to a LB backend

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

The way I have my services set up is the following:

deployment (2 pods) -> load balancer routes to this deployment -> ingress point terminating https pointing to the load balancer as the backend.

So far it's serving the correct cert, but for some reasons it's pointing to the "wrong" backend. On the GKE wbeconsole it just says my backend services are unhealthy, once I click on them they don't exist. What am I doing wrong here?

```
[stupifatcatslaptop poc (dev)]$  kubectl get pods -o wide | grep my_project
my_project-flask-poc-696f7b57c5-54n6r         1/1       Running            0          13d       10.236.1.228   gke-qus1-shared-1-prod-default-pool-44da43de-vq4c
my_project-flask-poc-696f7b57c5-m57h7         1/1       Running            0          13d       10.236.0.16    gke-qus1-shared-1-prod-default-pool-b27de1c2-2h63
```

```
[stupifatcatslaptop poc (dev)]$ kubectl get services | grep my_project
my_project-flask-poc-lb                     LoadBalancer   {internal_ip_0}   {internal_ip_1}   8080:32133/TCP               33d
```

```
[stupifatcatslaptop poc (dev)]$ kubectl get ingress
NAME                       HOSTS                          ADDRESS          PORTS     AGE
my_project-flask-poc-ingress   my_project-flask-poc.mydomain.com   {external_ip}   80, 443   1d
```

This is my ingress yaml file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my_project-flask-poc-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my_project-poc-tls
  rules:
  - host: my_project-flask-poc.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my_project-flask-poc-lb
          servicePort: 8080
```

deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my_project-flask-poc
  labels:
    app: my_project-flask-poc
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my_project-flask-poc
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my_project-flask-poc
          image: gcr.io/myprojectid/my_project-flask-poc
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
          - name: secrets
            mountPath: "/etc/secrets"
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: secrets
        secret:
          secretName: my_project-secret-poc
```

lb service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my_project-flask-poc-lb
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: {someinternalip} 
  selector:
    app: my_project-flask-poc
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
```

Comment: can you show the deployment and service yaml?

Comment: @chriscross just added the config yamls

Comment: Now I understand your question. I am not sure if this possible. The ingress automatically provisions a GCLB load balancer (L7). Using the Google Cloud Console you can choose your backend services when setting up a L7 load balancer manually (without yaml)

Comment: So maybe I'm taking the wrong approach, all I want is to terminate SSL and point to my LB, is it possible to terminate SSL without the usage of an ingress point?

Comment: I don't think so. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950590/kubernetes-service-loadbalancer-with-https

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to GKE, [only GCE ingress type manages your SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#ssl_certificates), hence, is the only option that has LB-level SSL termination.

For Kubernetes' `service type load balancer`, you will find that a Network Load Balancer is attached to the cluster. For this type of load balancer, the [SSL termination must be handled in the backend](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/#protocols_scheme_and_scope).

This is because SSL certificates are managed by layer 7 applications and the Network Load Balancer is working at layer 4, as [pointed in a previously shared answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50952128/10892354).